# In Pascal, is there a way to reverse the effect of the IntToBin() function?

Tags: pascal

Basically I was wondering if there was some way of taking a string that contains only 1s and 0s which represents a binary number and have it convert that to an integer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StrToInt` keeping in mind that `StrToInt` interprets strings using the Pascal conventions for integer constants. Binary constants are represented with a `%` prefix (*e.g.*, binary `101001` would be represented as `%101001`). So, you could prepend a `%` (used to indicate a binary constant) then use `StrToInt`:

```
var
  x: Integer;
  s: string;

...
s := '101001';
...
x := StrToInt( '%' + s );
writeln(x);
```

This will print `41`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this:

```
  function BinToInt(const BinStr: string): integer;
  var
    Multiplier: integer;
    i: byte;
  begin
    Multiplier := 1;
    result := 0;
    for i := High(BinStr) downto Low(BinStr) do
    begin
      if BinStr[i] = '1' then
        result := result + Multiplier;
      Multiplier := Multiplier * 2; // or := Multiplier shl 1;
    end;
  end;
```

You may also add the code checking the owerflow if the string is too long.